# How to get current top activity context

Tags: java, android

In my static method(Parameter is only one string), I want to use Dialog(`new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)`), but dialog needs an activity context to construct. If I do not pass through the external context parameters, only by reflection or other methods, how to get an object of current top activity?

```
public static Activity getActivity() {
    Class activityThreadClass = null;
    try {
        activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
        Object activityThread = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentActivityThread").invoke(null);
        Field activitiesField = activityThreadClass.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
        activitiesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map activities = (Map) activitiesField.get(activityThread);
        for (Object activityRecord : activities.values()) {
            Class activityRecordClass = activityRecord.getClass();
            Field pausedField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("paused");
            pausedField.setAccessible(true);
            if (!pausedField.getBoolean(activityRecord)) {
                Field activityField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("activity");
                activityField.setAccessible(true);
                Activity activity = (Activity) activityField.get(activityRecord);
                return activity;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I used this code, but when I call this method in non-Activity class, the `activities` is null.

Is there any other way? Can not use dialog, as long as it is able to pop up the information can be seen by the user. A point limit: does not get context from the parameter.

Comment: It looks like you are going about this backwards. Instead of trying to *find* the top `Activity`, you should probably be invoking the `Dialog` from the `Activity`; don't fight the framework. What is it that you are trying to do? Why do you need to *find* the top `Activity` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Implementation example:

```
class ActivityLifeCycleCallbackImpl implements  Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private Set<Activity> set = new HashSet<>();


    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        set.add(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        set.remove(activity);

    }

    Activity getCurrentActivity() {
        if (set.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return set.iterator().next();
    }


}
```

and in your custom application class:

```
    ActivityLifeCycleCallbackImpl activityLifeCycleCallback = new ActivityLifeCycleCallbackImpl();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityLifeCycleCallback);

}
```

Comment: ActivityLifeCycleCallbackImpl can solve my problem ~ thanks